# How to properly satisfy the borrow checker when conditionally creating a vector

Tags: rust

So, I want to create a vector (because the length is not known at compile time) that isn't mutable (because when I create it is the last time I will modify it). Basically I'm either getting a value from a file, or value(s) from command line arguments, and then iterating over those values later.

I wanted to do

```
/* other file
pub struct Settings {
  pub repo_name: String,
}
pub fn get_settings() -> Result<Settings, ConfigError>
*/

let settings = get_settings();
let args = App.blah.get_matches(); //clap::ArgMatches
let repos: Vec<_>;
if args.is_present("repo") {
    repos = args.values_of("repo").unwrap().collect(); // https://docs.rs/clap/2.31.1/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html#method.values_of
} else {
    // I want repos to own the value I clone here
    repos = vec![settings.repo_name.clone()];
}
```

For this, vec! wanted a reference. If I used a refernce with clone(), the reference lifetime ended before the assignment. 
If I created a new variable, the lifetime ended at the end of the block. 
If I directly borrowed from settings, I blocked other uses later.

In the end, I made it work with

```
let default_repo = settings.repo_name.clone();
if args.is_present("repo") {
    repos = args.values_of("repo").unwrap().collect();
} else {
    repos = vec![&default_repo];
}
```

But I wonder if there is a way to actually gives `repos` the ownership of the value in the new vector?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because the code contains a lot of names that are not defined. For example, without knowing what type `args` is,  we can't tell what type the `Vec` should contain. Please [edit] the question to contain a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to decide on the type of `repos`.

- `repos = args.values_of("repo").unwrap().collect()` creates a `Vec<&str>`, i.e. a vector of slices
- `repos = vec![settings.repo_name.clone()];` creates a `Vec<String>`

If you decide to go with `Vec<&str>` (less copying, but you have to care more about lifetimes), you could change the second to `repos = vec![&settings.repo_name]`. For this to work, `settings` must live long enough.

If you decide to go with `Vec<String>`, you could change the first to `repos = args.values_of("repo").unwrap().map(|s|s.to_string()).collect()`.

Another option is the following: Completely omit the vector and - instead - introduce another function taking an iterator, and simply call this function with either `values_of("repo").unwrap()` or with `std::iter::once(repo_name)`.

Comment: Assuming you're correct about the nature of the problem, you could also create a `Vec<Cow<str>>` by wrapping the items in `Cow::Borrowed` or `Cow::Owned`, respectively.

Comment: Settings gets used at the same time as repos later, so it complains about borrow conflicts, which is fair. Some of it I got away from by using all clones when using settings, but even then< I think it's blocked if we borrow for repos, because it's inside the loop where I go through repos.

I will explore the function with an iterator, I think that sounds like a good choice.

Is pushing things into a function to isolate the borrows a specific idiomatic rust thing?

Comment: You could try to separate `settings` from `repos` then (i.e. create a struct `AllSettings` with two fields: `settings` (contains settings *without* repos) and `repos` (contains repos)). That would lead to having non-overlapping borrows.